# android emulator built from source won't boot up

Tags: android, build, emulation, boot

I downloaded the Android source and built version 2.3.7 (for emulator) with the guide in :
http://source.android.com/source/building.html

It finished with no errors and I got three .img files (about 86 MB total) in the output folder.

Then I typed "`emulator`" command to start an emulator.
But the emulator just won't boot up. It was stuck at a black screen with CPU running at 100%.
I waited for about 10 mins and it still did not boot up.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got similar problem as u.

Instead of running emulator, I run below command:

out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator -sysdir out/target/product/generic/ -system out/target/product/generic/system.img -ramdisk out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img -data out/target/product/generic/userdata.img **-kernel prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu** -sdcard sdcard.img -skindir sdk/emulator/skins -skin WVGA800 -scale 0.7 -memory 512 -partition-size 1024

Then I change the bold to *prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu-armv7*

And my problem was fixed.