# Android Build - Emulator stuck on android boot logo

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-build

I was experimenting with the Android build system for couple of days. I could download and build the system successfully as described [here](http://source.android.com/source/building.html). I built the master branch.

Instead of running `emulator` command alone I used the command with the parameters given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716169/1230782). The emulator window launched and shown the "android" logo, but it stuck there. I left it for almost 1 hour but it looked like entered in to some kind of boot loop. When checked the logcat I could find some "connection failed" logs like below.

```
I/PackageManager(  283): /system/app/Launcher2.apk changed; collecting certs
D/dalvikvm(  283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 460K, 36% free 5704K/8808K, paused 15ms+24ms, total 170ms
I/Installer(  283): connecting...
I/Installer(  283): disconnecting...
E/Installer(  283): connection failed
I/PackageManager(  283): /system/app/LiveWallpapers.apk changed; collecting certs
D/dalvikvm(  283): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1182K, 43% free 5049K/8808K, paused 6ms+9ms, total 125ms
I/Installer(  283): connecting...
I/Installer(  283): disconnecting...
E/Installer(  283): connection failed
I/PackageManager(  283): /system/app/LiveWallpapersPicker.apk changed; collecting certs
I/Installer(  283): connecting...
I/Installer(  283): disconnecting...
E/Installer(  283): connection failed
I/PackageManager(  283): /system/app/MagicSmokeWallpapers.apk changed; collecting certs
I/Installer(  283): connecting...
I/Installer(  283): disconnecting...
E/Installer(  283): connection failed
I/PackageManager(  283): /system/app/MediaProvider.apk changed; collecting certs
I/Installer(  283): connecting...
I/Installer(  283): disconnecting...
E/Installer(  283): connection failed
```

These messages are showing for almost all APK and continues in a loop. The system have internet access but somehow emulator fails to connect to network I think.

Any possible workarounds?

**Update:30/09**
Running the emulator command soon after the build, didn't work either. I's not showing the android logo at all.

Comment: I don't believe its a network issue, I think the connection failed is from your IDE not being able to connect to the emulator to install the app. This doesn't use network as it is local but because the emulator is in a boot loop it is not allowing eclipse to connect to install the APK

Comment: It might be worth reducing the memory allocated to the emulator, try reducing it 512 and tick the checkbox for use GPU. Then restart the emulator and see if it makes any difference

Comment: @Boardy, I am neither launching emulator from IDE nor installing any app. I am launching one which is built from code.

Answer (score 4):

set your ram size to `512 mb` and start the `emulator`